Next.js next-auth decryption operation failed
Использую next-auth
export const authOptions = {
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET!,
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID!,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET!,
    }),
  ],
  pages: {
    signIn: "/auth/signin",
  },
};

но получаю ошибку [ Server ] [next-auth][error][JWT_SESSION_ERROR] "\nhttps://next-auth.js.org/errors#jwt_session_error" "decryption operation failed" {}
может кто-то уже сталкивался с подобной проблемой, буду благодарна помощи
